# adding tooltip to graphics in arcgis javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to open tooltip on "mouse-over" event of a layer which has graphices

Bellow is my code

```
  <script>
        var map, dialog;

        require([
          "esri/map", "esri/geometry/Circle", "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
          "esri/graphic", "esri/geometry/Point", "esri/Color", "esri/dijit/geoenrichment/Infographic", "esri/tasks/geoenrichment/RingBuffer",
          "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer","dojo/dom-style", "esri/lang",
        "dijit/TooltipDialog", "dijit/popup", "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function (
          Map, Circle, SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol,
          Graphic, Point, Color, Infographic, RingBuffer,GraphicsLayer, domStyle,esriLang,
        TooltipDialog, dijitPopup
        ) {
            map = new Map("map", {
                basemap: "streets",
                center: [-77.036744, 38.897731],
                zoom: 12
            });

            var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(null).outline.setColor("blue");
            var gl = new GraphicsLayer({ id: "circles" });
            var pt = new GraphicsLayer({ id: "point" });

            map.addLayer(pt);
            map.addLayer(gl);
            map.infoWindow.resize(245, 125);

            dialog = new TooltipDialog({
                id: "tooltipDialog",
                style: "position: absolute; width: 250px; font: normal normal normal 10pt Helvetica;z-index:100"
            });
            dialog.startup();

            pt.on("mouse-over", function (evt) {
                var t = '<select id="dropDistance"><option value="5">5</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="20">20</option></select>';

                var content = esriLang.substitute(evt.graphic.attributes, t);

                dialog.setContent(content);

                domStyle.set(dialog.domNode, "opacity", 0.85);
                dijitPopup.open({
                    popup: dialog,
                    x: evt.pageX,
                    y: evt.pageY
                });
            });

            map.on("load", function () {
                var symbolPoint = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 10,
     new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([255, 0, 0]), 1),
     new Color([0, 255, 0, 0.25]));
                point = new Point([-77.036744, 38.897731]);
                var pointGraphic = new Graphic(point, symbolPoint);
                pt.add(pointGraphic);

                $(document).ready(jQueryReady);
            });

            function jQueryReady() {
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Div of tooltip is not comming properly here. I am not able to understand what is problem in this.